# Perl Script to Generate All Characters Including NonLetters: How do I transform a number into base 27?

Tags: perl, character, generator

I have written the following script that creates a string that is of length 3 or 4 units for all possible strings that contain the 26 letters of the alphabet.  I'd like to add a 27th character.  Call it `?`, but it does not matter which one.  I cannot think how I should do this.  Any help would be much welcomed.

Here is the code that does the 26 letters:

```
 #!/usr/bin/perl

 use 5.10.0;

 my $str = 'AAA';
 while ( $str ne 'ZZZZ' ) {
    say $str;
    $str++;
  }
```

How would I transform a number into base 27?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[perldoc perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html):

> The auto-increment operator has a little extra builtin magic to it. If you increment a variable that is numeric, or that has ever been used in a numeric context, you get a normal increment. If, however, the variable has been used in only string contexts since it was set, and has a value that is not the empty string and matches the pattern `/^[a-zA-Z]*[0-9]*\z/`, the increment is done as a string, preserving each character within its range, with carry …

[Algorithm::Combinatorics](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Algorithm%3a%3aCombinatorics) to the rescue!

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use Algorithm::Combinatorics qw(variations_with_repetition);

my $digits = ['A' .. 'Z', '?'];

print_sequence($digits, 3);

sub print_sequence {
    my ($digits, $n) = @_;

    my $it = variations_with_repetition($digits, $n);
    while (my $v = $it->next) {
        say join '', @$v;
    }

    return;
}
```

Comment: `s/while.*?\}/'say $calc->to_base($_) for $start .. $end;'/e` Range operator and for-loops ftw.

Comment: @amon Changed the answer to use `Math::Combinatorics` before I saw your note.

Comment: @SinanÜnür Ah, that is even better :-)

Answer (score 1):

As an alternate solution you could use some for loops and iterate over ASCII values.  It isn't the best looking script but it will generate the values for you.  You can easily modify it to print whatever extra character you want.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict; 
use warnings;
use 5.10.0;

my $str = 65;

my ($i, $j, $k, $l);
for ($i = $str; $i < 92; $i++) {
    for ($j = $str; $j < 92; $j++) {
        for ($k = $str; $k < 92; $k++) {
            say chr($i), chr($j), chr($k);
            for ($l = $str; $l < 92; $l++) {
                say chr($i), chr($j), chr($k), chr($l);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is an ASCII table reference: http://www.asciitable.com/

Comment: ① Why don't you use the shorter range operator: `for my $i (ord("A") .. ord("[")) {...}`? Note also the self-documenting use of `ord` as the inverse of `chr`. ② Since 5.10 the `say` function can be used instead of `print` – appends a newline. ③ We can shorten the `print` line to `say map chr, $i, $j, $k`. `chr` operates on `$_` if no argument is given.

Comment: @amon I forgot to put `say` for some reason. As for the other suggestions, there is always more than one way to do it.

Comment: @user2096518 It is a non-CPAN way to do it :).  Thought I would include it just as a different route, cheers.

Answer (score 0):

The string increment in Perl is “magic”. This unfortunately means that you can't (easily) extend the alphabet it iterates over.

The problem is rather simple to solve if you rephrase your problem:

> How do I transform a number into base 27?

There is code “out there” to do that. Your digits are the characters “a”–“z”, and “?”. Then you increment a counter, and transform each value into a different base/your string.

Comment: @user2096518 CPAN contains tons of modules ready for you to use, or study their code. As this problem is mathematical you will find appropriate modules in the `Math::` namespace. Here is a [start](https://metacpan.org/search?q=Math%3A%3ABase).